# How can I achive a fold out text in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, animation, button, dropdown

I want a fold out text in my Android Studio application.
I designet it with paint so you can understand what I mean:

Folds:
https://gyazo.com/cda3fc81d662c5ed0a7da1debbee6107

Fold out:
https://gyazo.com/06dfd2477517a93f9d65100e549e4d70

Please say me the correct name of it, so I can google it.
Or can you send me a tutorial link?
Or is this not possible in Android Studio?

Comment: Expandable listView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Android Expandable List View Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/)

See Above Tutorial it has solution for your problem.

Expandable list view is used to group list data by categories. It has the capability of expanding and collapsing the groups when user touches header.